# 502 Bad Gateway error when backend services communicate to produce response to web app

Tags: nginx, nestjs, cloudflare

I have the following setup:

- CloudFlare(CF) for caching, SSL, etc.
- Nginx(NG) for reverse proxy
- Docker for load balancing via DNS resolver
- Apps & Services (webapp, recipes_service, products_service)

For the sake of simplicity, I'll remove "webapp" from the equation - as it's obsolete, it only makes api calls.

**The following works:**

- sent GET /api/recipes to domain (managed by CF)
- CF resolves DNS, sends request to server (managed by NG)
- NG gets request, proxies it to recipes_service
- recipes_service receives request
- recipes_service returns 200 OK, data

**The following works:**

- sent GET /api/products to domain (managed by CF)
- CF resolves DNS, sends request to server (managed by NG)
- NG gets request, proxies it to products_service
- products_service receives request
- products_service returns 200 OK, data

**The following DOESN'T work:**

- sent GET /api/recipes/fresh to domain (managed by CF)
- CF resolves DNS, sends request to server (managed by NG)
- NG gets request, proxies it to recipes_service
- recipes_service receives request
- recipes_service sends GET /api/products/fresh/:id to domain (managed by CF)
- CF resolves DNS, sends request to server (managed by NG)
- NG gets request, proxies it to products_service
- products_service receives request
- products_service returns 200 OK, data
- recipes_service receives response
- recipes_service returns 502 Bad Gateway

There isn't much in logs - I can see that both products_service and recipes_service get their requests and responses - but the last response simply fails.

The only logs I have to go by are these:
error.logs

```
2024/03/15 18:56:51 [error] 41#41: *211 upstream sent "Content-Length" and "Transfer-Encoding" headers at the same time while reading response header from upstream, client: <ip>, server: api.example.com, request: "GET /api/recipes/fresh HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://<ip>>:3030/recipes/fresh", host: "api.example.com"
```

access.logs

```
<ip> - - - api.example.com api.example.com to: <ip of products_service>:3020: GET /api/products/fresh HTTP/2.0 200 upstream_response_time 0.135 msec 1710529217.923 request_time 0.135
<ip> - - - api.example.com api.example.com to: <ip of recipes_service>:3030: GET /api/recipes/fresh HTTP/2.0 502 upstream_response_time 0.247 msec 1710529217.933 request_time 0.247
```

Comment: The error makes sense as those headers are mutually exclusive. Try to find out what part of the stack is generating these headers and remove one.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/482875/why-does-nginx-remove-content-length-header-for-chunked-content more details